# how to pass two Strings in "StringRequest" in android

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking

i want to get data from two different tables in MYSQL so i used "StringRequest" method to retrieve data from MYSQL, In the below code i can get data from one table and view it in ListView in android but how i can change my code so that i will get data from another table too.

here is my code:

```
 String url ="http://alwaysready.16mb.com/OnlineJobSort.php;";
 String url_lock="http://alwaysready.16mb.com/LocalSort.php?";

  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Jobs.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

From the above code i can able to get data from "url" but i need to get data from both "url"&"url_lock".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's simple. You just need to make 2 StringRequests with different URL parameter

```
String url = "http://alwaysready.16mb.com/OnlineJobSort.php;";
String url_lock = "http://alwaysready.16mb.com/LocalSort.php?";

StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        showJSON(response);
    }
},
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Jobs.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

StringRequest stringRequest2 = new StringRequest(url_lock, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        showJSON(response);
    }
},
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Jobs.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest1);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest2);
```

Comment: sir in my case the second call always get called first and first one in second or at last. Which cause the error like client error as in first call I get the id to work with in request2. I have tried to call the second request in response of first but nothing comes up. Please help me.